# How to reach this result using only matrix operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

$$\mathbf{Xw}-\lambda_w \mathbf{1}=0$$

Where $\lambda_w$ is a scalar, $\mathbf{w}$ is a vector, and $\mathbf{X}$ is a symmetric p.d. matrix.  It is known that $\mathbf{1'w}=1$ (but I don't think that matters too much for the present question).

This equation can be rewritten:

$$\mathbf{X}=\lambda_w \mathbf{D^{-1}}$$

where $\mathbf{D}=diag(\mathbf{w})$.

One more thing:

$$\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{\Sigma-\lambda_{\mu}R}$$

Where $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ and $\mathbf{R}$ are symmetric, p.d. matrices and $\lambda_{\mu}$ is another scalar.

The basic goal here is to solve for the $\mathbf{w}$ that make the first displayed equation true.  $\lambda_w$ is known but $\lambda_{\mu}$ is not.

So, for example, in the simple case of a 2x2 matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 \Sigma_{11}-\lambda_{\mu}R_{11} & \Sigma_{12}-\lambda_{\mu}R_{12}\\ 
 \Sigma_{21}-\lambda_{\mu}R_{21} & \Sigma_{22}-\lambda_{\mu}R_{22}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 \lambda_w/w_1 & 0\\ 
 0 & \lambda_w/w_2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Here you can see the off diagonal elements on the LHS have to sum to $0$, so:

$$\lambda_{\mu}=\frac{\Sigma_{ij}}{R_{ij}}$$

From the diagonal elements, on the other hand, we can get the following equation:

$$\lambda_{\mu}=\frac{1}{R_{ii}}\left(\Sigma_{ii}-\frac{\lambda_w}{w_i}\right)$$

Setting these two equations equal gives:

$$\frac{\lambda_w}{w_i}=\frac{\Sigma_{ii}R_{ij}-R_{ii}\Sigma_{ij}}{R_{ij}} \:\:\:\: \forall \: j \neq i$$

But the LHS are just the diagonal elements of the matrix $\lambda_w\mathbf{D^{-1}}$.  Therefore the second displayed equation can be rewritten:

$$\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{\lambda_w D^{-1}}=\mathbf{Q}$$

where the elements of $\mathbf{Q}$ are defined:

$$Q_{ij}\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{\Sigma_{ii}R_{ij}-R_{ii}\Sigma_{ij}}{R_{ij}} \:\:\:\: (\forall \: j \neq i) \:\:for \:\:on \:\: diagonal\:\: elements\\ 
\frac{\Sigma_{ii}R_{ij}-R_{ii}\Sigma_{ij}}{R_{ij}} \:\:\:\:  (j = i) \:\:for \:\:off \:\:diagonal\:\:elements
\end{matrix}\right.$$

For example in the 2x2 case,

$$\mathbf{Q}=\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\Sigma_{11}R_{12}-R_{11}\Sigma_{12}}{R_{12}} & \frac{\Sigma_{11}R_{11}-R_{11}\Sigma_{11}}{R_{12}} \\ 
 \frac{\Sigma_{22}R_{22}-R_{22}\Sigma_{22}}{R_{22}} & \frac{\Sigma_{22}R_{21}-R_{22}\Sigma_{21}}{R_{21}}
\end{bmatrix}$$

So the question is: can I derive the matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ using only matrix operations?  Is there a more tidy way to define the elements of $\mathbf{Q}$?

Comment: You're ignoring some potential solutions to that first equation: $$X=(\lambda_w-\mu_w)\,D^{-1} + \mu_w\,11^T $$

Comment: @lynn Where did $\mu_w$ come from?  Do you mean $\lambda_{\mu}$?  Would appreciate it if you could explain in a little more detail how you reached this solution.  Might even accept it as an answer.

Comment: I was merely pointing out that unless $X$ is known to be diagonal, there are other solutions to the first equation.  Since you stated that $1^Tw=1$, one possible non-diagonal solution is $$X=\lambda_w11^T$$  My earlier comment was simply a linear combination of your diagonal solution and my non-diagonal solution. The parameter $\mu_w$ has no relationship to your $\lambda_\mu$ parameter. As long as $\mu_w < \lambda_w$ the matrix is positive definite.

Comment: For a more general expression for $X$, you should add contributions from the nullspace projector. $$N=I-\frac{ww^T}{w^Tw}$$ Since $N.w=0$ you can add an arbitrary amount, so that brings us to $$X=\alpha\,N + \beta\,11^T + (\lambda_w-\beta)\,D^{-1}$$